# How to use REST services hosted on Apache 2.2 via cURL to send SSL requests?

Tags: php, apache, curl, https

What is the procedure for sending secure data (login id, password) over https to an Apache 2.2 server with self-signed certificates?

```
<?php
$uid=$_POST['user'];
$password=$_POST['pass'];
$url = "https://example.com/login";
$cert_file = './certificate.com.pem';
$cert_password = 'xxxxxx';

$ch = curl_init();

$options = array( 
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_HEADER         => true,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => 'uid:'.$uid.'&password:'.$password,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_VERBOSE        => true,
    CURLOPT_URL => $url ,
    CURLOPT_SSLCERT => $cert_file ,
    CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD => $cert_password ,
    CURLOPT_POST => true
);

curl_setopt_array($ch , $options);

$output = curl_exec($ch);

if(!$output)
{
    echo "Curl Error : " . curl_error($ch);
}
else
{
    echo htmlentities($output);
}
?>
```

the ERROR we are getting is  :
curl error:unable to use client certificate (no key found or wrong passphrase ?)

Comment: Do you mean so that the fingerprint of the cert can be checked? The basic action of sending the data is the same, as far as I know. Do you have any code at the moment?

Comment: (Btw, it is usually the case here that readers like to see a reasonable research/search effort first - questions sometimes are put on hold for lack of it).

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to think about it this way:

- Your local server asks the remote server to validate the login info. — You would need to make an exception for the self-signed certificate and remember it. (It would be a really a bad habit to simply ignore certificate errors.)
- Your local server then checks if the data the remote one sent back isn't an error message and is indeed valid JSON data.

Here's some info on how to make curl remember the self-signed certificate and trust it permanently: http://turboflash.wordpress.com/2009/06/23/curl-adding-installing-trusting-new-self-signed-certificate/ — It should work for the command-line utility just as well as the PHP module.

So, let's make a little function for it. — I'm not going to test its functionality, so I can't promise to have it perfectly error free. I'm also using some practices I wouldn't use in production code, don't account for an API key, use GET parameters and I also make the remote server responsible for any serious sort of error checking and sanitation.

```
<?php
    function remote_login($username, $password) {        

        /*
        Initialize the curl object
        */
        $login = curl_init();

        /*
        Some sanitation. This is probably not enough though.
        */
        $username = urlencode($username);
        $password = urlencode($password);

        /*
        Set the url we're going to use.
        REST services use clean urls, but here we simply use GET parapeters.
        */
        $login_url = 'https://example.com/?username='+$username+'&password='+$password;
        curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_URL, $login_url);

        /*
        Tell curl we would like to use the data returned from the remote server
        */
        curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        /*
        Set the returned data as a variable
        */
        $login_data = curl_exec($login);
        $login_json = json_decode($login_data);

        /*
        We're not going to do anything else if we encounter any sort of error.
        */
        if (($login_data == false) || ($login_json == false)) {
            return false;
        }

        /*
        Return the login result as a JSON object
        */
        return json_decode($login_data);
    }
?>
```

Hope this helps.